# RTSP: error while decoding MB

Tags: c++, opencv, stream, rtsp

I have problem with RTSP stream from my BOSH cammera. While Im getting stream  to my program with this code:

```
VideoCapture cap("rtsp://name:password@IPaddress:554");
```

i get some stream, but after few images i get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubElH.png)

and then, my stream looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtHdW.jpg)

I saw that there are more solutions for my problem, like using VLC libraries to resolve my problem, or GStreamer. But this is no solution for my problem, because I need to use OPenCV libraries, save every image to MATRIX, and Im then using my special image processing.. 
Does anybody have solution ? 
Is it possible to create some buffer ? If answer yes, can anybody write HOW ?
Here is my code:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat frame;
    namedWindow("video", 1);
    VideoCapture cap("rtsp://name:password@IPaddress:554");

    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"Camera not found"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if(frame.empty()) break;
        resize(frame, frame, Size(1200, 800), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
        imshow("video", frame);
        if(waitKey(1000) >= 0) break;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```